# Find error - unknown primary or operator

Tags: bash, unix, sh

```
find /Volumes/COMMON-LIC-PHOTO/STAGING/Completed -type d -maxdepth 2 -iname -iregex '.*_OUTPUT' -exec rsync -rtWv --stats --progress {} /Volumes/COMMON-LIC-PHOTO/ASPERA/ASPERA_STAGING/ \;
```

The code above is designed to look inside the directory *Complete* for any sub-directories with the phrase "_OUTPUT" (ignoring case, hence `-iname`) at the end of the directory name and copy what it finds to a new location, *Aspera_Staging*. I'm running the code in a .sh triggered by the launchcd app Launch Control whenever a new directory is moved to *Complete* (which could be part of the issue because cron seems to be very picky).

It works about half the time, the other half it does nothing at all. An OUTPUT directory won't be copied. I can't find a pattern, it almost seems random. I've noticed in the debug log that it is giving me the following error:

> find: .*_OUTPUT: unknown primary or operator

I've spent hours tinkering, trying to figure it out. I've followed a lot of suggestions found on here and other sites but so far nothing has worked. It obviously has something to do with it looking for the Output folders but I just can't get to the bottom of it.

Comment: You're missing an argument after the `-iname` immediately prior to that `-iregex`. You can't combine `-iname` and `-iregex` like that. Each of them expects an argument.

Comment: Okay I see. I didn't write this code originally btw, I'm trying to fix it. I tried adding `'OUTPUT'` between `-iname` and `-iregex` (eg. `-iname 'OUTPUT' -iregex '.*_OUTPUT'`to see if that argument worked for `-iname` but I still have the same result, it ignores the OUTPUT folder.

Comment: If you have `-iname 'OUTPUT'`, it will be looking for items with the exact name `OUTPUT`, not items ending in `_OUTPUT`. Also, it sounds like you probably don't need both `-iname` and `-iregex`. Try removing the `-iregex '.*_OUTPUT'` and just do `-iname '*_output'`.

Comment: Also, keep in that there is an implied logical "AND" operator between each of the "test" arguments you provide to `find`. Read the `man` page regarding which arguments are so-called "tests". In your example, `-type`, `-iname`, and `-iregex` are tests. So if you did have `-iname 'OUTPUT' -iregex '.*_OUTPUT'`, then (ignoring case insensitivity for the moment) `find` would only return directories with the exact name `OUTPUT` *and* that match the regular expression `'.*_OUTPUT'`. Note that the intersection of those two sets is empty, so `find` will never return any results.

Comment: So the good news is that removing `-iregex` completely eliminates the "unknown primary or operator" error from the debug, the bad news is that it's still not copying any Output folders to *Aspera_Staging*.

Comment: Try putting an `echo` in front of the `rsync` command, just to verify that the resulting `rsync` command looks like you're expecting it to. Also, just remove the whole `-exec` clause entirely and verify that `find` is finding the correct source directories.

Comment: Just to be clear, is the name of the folder `Aspera_Staging`, or `ASPERA_STAGING`? File and directory names are case sensitive in Linux, and even on Windows if you're running this script in Cygwin.

Answer (score 1):

As commenters have noticed, `-iname` requires a parameter, therefore the `-iregex` that follows is understood as that parameter and the parameter to `-iregex` is (mis)taken as an operator, hence your error message.

In your context, `-iname` and `-iregex` seem redundant, so your command should be either:

```
find /Volumes/COMMON-LIC-PHOTO/STAGING/Completed -type d -maxdepth 2 -iname '*_OUTPUT' -exec ... \;
```

or:

```
find /Volumes/COMMON-LIC-PHOTO/STAGING/Completed -type d -maxdepth 2 -iregex '.*_OUTPUT' -exec ... \;
```

(notice how the parameters to `-iname` and to `-iregex` slightly differ)